# Find Duplicate in Text file

Tags: php, file, text

I cannot figure out how to resolve this "feof(): 3 is not valid steam resources" error. I need to be able to take input from user and cross reference with data in the List.txt file and make sure its not duplicate before writing. 
any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>  
        <form action="List.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="open" value="Open in Text Editor" /><br />
        </form>

    <?php
    $myArray = array();

    if (isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $toString = $_POST['name']. " ". $_POST['email'];
        $fp = fopen("List.txt", 'w');
        while (!feof($fp)) {
           $line = fgets($fp);
           if(strcmp($toString,$line)==0) {
               echo "<h1>Duplicate entery.</h1>"; 
           }
           else {
               $fp1 = fopen("List.txt", 'a');   
               fwrite($fp, $name);
               fwrite($fp, $email);
               echo "<h1>Success. U have been added to list.</h1>";   
            }
            fclose($fp);
         }
      }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've only set it for writing only

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the stream in your `while` loop. Move your `fclose($fp);` out of the loop, and set the stream mode to `w+` like this:

```
$fp = fopen("List.txt", 'w+');
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp);
  if(strcmp($toString,$line)==0) {
    echo "<h1>Duplicate entery.</h1>"; 
  }
  else {
    $fp1 = fopen("List.txt", 'a');   
    fwrite($fp, $name);
    fwrite($fp, $email);
    echo "<h1>Success. U have been added to list.</h1>";   
  }
  //fclose($fp); move this out
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This code seems to work but it overwrites the existing data. Any way i can save the data on the next line

Comment: Replace the `mode` parameter of `fopen` with `a+`. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).